# Recording multiple canvas using MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, canvas, mediarecorder

I want to record the multiple layered canvas using **MediaRecorder**.
But, i don't know how to achieve it...
help me...

this is the my pseudo code

```js
const RECORD_FRAME = 30;

const canvasVideoTrack = canvas.captureStream(RECORD_FRAME).getVideoTracks()[0];
const waterMarkCanvasTrack = waterMarkCanvas.captureStream(RECORD_FRAME).getVideoTracks()[0];

const stream= new MediaStream();
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

mediaRecorder.stream.addTrack(canvasVideoTrack)
mediaRecorder.stream.addTrack(waterMarkCanvasTrack)

// .... recording
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: Start reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder or https://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/ or https://developer.chrome.com/blog/mediarecorder/ etc.

Comment: You' ll need to draw all your canvases on a single one

Comment: @jasie thank you for advice.
i will read the articles you shared

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw all your canvases on a single one.
Even if we could record multiple video streams (which we can't yet), what you need is to composite these video streams. And for this, you use a canvas:

```js
const prepareCanvasAnim = (color, offset) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  let x = offset;
  const anim = () => {
    x = (x + 1) % canvas.width;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(x, offset, 50, 50);
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
  anim();
  return canvas;
}

const canvas1 = prepareCanvasAnim("red", 20);
const canvas2 = prepareCanvasAnim("green", 80);
document.querySelector(".container").append(canvas1, canvas2);

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const record = (evt) => {
  btn.textContent = "Stop Recording";
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => btn.disabled = false, 5000); // at least 5s recording
  // prepare our merger canvas
  const canvas = canvas1.cloneNode();
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  const toMerge = [canvas1, canvas2];
  const anim = () => {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    toMerge.forEach(layer => ctx.drawImage(layer, 0, 0));
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
  anim();
  const stream = canvas.captureStream();
  const chunks = [];
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = (evt) => chunks.push(evt.data);
  recorder.onstop = (evt) => exportVid(chunks);
  btn.onclick = (evt) => recorder.stop();
  recorder.start();
};
function exportVid(chunks) {
  const vid = document.createElement("video");
  vid.controls = true;
  vid.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(chunks));
  document.body.append(vid);
  btn.onclick = record;
  btn.textContent = "Start Recording";
}
btn.onclick = record;
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
.container canvas { position: absolute }
.container:hover canvas { position: relative }
.container { height: 180px }
```

```html
<div class="container">Hover here to "untangle" the canvases<br></div>
<button>Start Recording</button><br>
```

But if you're going this way anyway, you might just as well do the merging from the get-go and append a single canvas in the document, the browser's compositor will have less work to do.

Comment: thanks you for reply
I prefer to use multiple layered canvas instead of one canvas because of performance issue. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas)

However, it seems that only one canvas is used to record.

Comment: That article is full of .... nonsense to stay polite. Don't follow what it says. The page compositor will have to do the job of compositing these layers just the same as the canvas, except that it will have to do so while in a far more complex environment: any other element in the page could interfere with this composition. Doing it yourself using the 2D context API is by far the most performant way of doing.

Comment: And yes, to record the composited stream, you **must** do the compositing yourself, on a single canvas. If you absolutely want to keep the two canvases setup, I shown in the snippet how to do so. But once again, if you did separarate your canvases just for perfs, then stop doing that.